# Any similar function of LogInv (in Excel) in SAS?

Tags: sas

I'm trying to figure out if there is any similar function of LogInv (returns the inverse of lognormal cdf in SAS? In Excel, the function is:

=LogInv(p, mean, st. deviation)

Is there a function in SAS that replicates this process? Or something similar?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [quantile](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/69762/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0uhywbqfucg6qn18woziy41flqp.htm) function is the inverse of the CDF in SAS.  To use it with the Lognormal distribution, you simply provide that as the first parameter.

```
data qdf;
  q = quantile('LOGNORMAL',0.2,0,1);
  put q=;
run;
```

That yields 0.431 which is identical to the result of `=LOGINV(0.2,0,1)`.

Rick Wicklin goes into some detail in his [blog post about using the inverse CDF here](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/07/22/the-inverse-cdf-method.html), including some examples.